# Output of the following C++ Program

Tags: c++, function, loops, math, recursion

Hi I've got this basic code exercise the code for the c++ program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int func(int x){
 if ( x==0)
     return 2;
 else if  ( x==1)
     return 3;
 else 
    return (func(x-1)+func(x-2));

}
int main()
{
 std::cout<<func(5)<<std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

I have compiled and ran this code. The Output is 21.

But I dont understand how the output comes out as 21 can someone please explain.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your program, step by step, in a debugger?

Comment: If your book doesn't cover recursive functions, throw it away and get a [better one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I love examples that can be broken by passing in a negative number...

Comment: @UKMonkey _"if x is negative, program behavior is undefined"_ . Here, I fixed it!

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot ahh yes; because all the best teaching starts by teaching bad habits, and then hoping they can be corrected later by someone else. :)

Comment: In the future, please explain in more specific detail what pieces are confusing you. People have tried to guess and have posted answers based on their guesses, but what if they guessed wrong? Then they wasted their time and yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can predict your output by following each step manually. In your case, each `func` call would work like the following chart:

```
func(5)
  +
  +--+ func(4)
  |      +
  |      +--+ func(3)
  |      |      +
  |      |      +--+ func(2)
  |      |      |      +
  |      |      |      +--+ func(1) = 3
  |      |      |      |
  |      |      |      +--+ func(0) = 2
  |      |      |
  |      |      +--+ func(1)        = 3
  |      |
  |      +--+ func(2)
  |             +
  |             +--+ func(1)        = 3
  |             |
  |             +--+ func(0)        = 2
  |
  +--+ func(3)
         +
         +--+ func(2)
         |      +
         |      +--+ func(1)        = 3
         |      |
         |      +--+ func(0)        = 2
         |
         +--+ func(1)               = 3
                              +-----------+
                                     21
```

Answer (score 4):

It works exactly like this non-recursive translation:

```
int func_0() { return 2; }

int func_1() { return 3; }

int func_2() { return func_1() + func_0(); } // Returns 3 + 2 = 5

int func_3() { return func_2() + func_1(); } // Returns 5 + 3 = 8

int func_4() { return func_3() + func_2(); } // Returns 8 + 5 = 13

int func_5() { return func_4() + func_3(); } // Returns 13 + 8 = 21

int main()
{
    std::cout << func_5() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the code is very small, you can predict the output by walking through the program physically, or you could use a debugger to step through.

Main is the entry point of your program; So the very first line that you should start with is `std::count<<funct(5)<<std::end1;`.

You enter the `func(int x)` method with an initial parameter x of 5. This function looks at the parameter and returns 2 or 3 if x is 0 or 1, respectively. Otherwise, it will [recursively](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Recursion) call itself, returning the sum of `func(x-1)` and `func(x-2)`.

Stepping through you get the following execution order:

```
func(5)
    func(4)
        func(3)
            func(2)
                func(1)
                    return 3
                func(0)
                    return 2
            func(1)
                return 3
        func(2)
            func(1)
                return 3
            func(0)
                return 2
    func(3)
        func(2)
            func(1)
                return 3
            func(0)
                return 2
        func(1)
            return 3

Which translates to -> 3 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 3 = 21
```

If you aren't too familiar with recursion in programming, the concept should already be vaguely familiar. You almost certainly have come across the 
[Fibonacci Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), where the next number in the sequence is the sum of the previous two (with the first two numbers of the sequence defined as 0 and 1). The program you presented is very similar to the Fibonacci Sequence, however, it uses 2 and 3 as the first two numbers.

Hence, if you define the recursive sequence as `a0 = 2, a1 = 3`, then `an = an-1 + an-2`, which looks very similar to the function defined.

Answer (score 1):

It is recursion so I runs like this

func is called with 5

```
func(4) + func(3)
func(3) + func(2) + func(2) + 3  
func(2) + func(1) + func(1) + func(0) + func(1) + func(0) + 3
func(1) + func(0) + 3 + 3 + 2 + 3 + 2 + 3
2 + 3 + 16
21
```

Comment: Hi Shyam thank so much for the explanation much appreciated.Can you please explain how does the +3  comes in on these lines                                    func(3) + func(2) + func(2) + 3  
func(2) + func(1) + func(1) + func(0) + func(1) + func(0) + 3

Comment: It is the value of func(1)